# Master-detail foreign key insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

Have two tables.

```
Customer              Contact
_______________________________________
CustomerId    *-->    CustomerId
CustomerName          ContactId
...                   ContactFirstName
                      ...

One customer can have many contacts
```

Stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCustomers
(
    @CustomerId int,
    @CustomerName nvarchar(50)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerName]) VALUES (@CustomerName);

SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM Customers WHERE (CustomerId = @CustomerId)
```

Second one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertContacts
(
    @CustomerId int,
    @ContactFirstName nvarchar(20)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Contacts] ([CustomerId], [ContactFirstName]) VALUES (@CustomerId, @ContactFirstName);

SELECT ContactId, CustomerId, ContactFirstName FROM Contacts WHERE (CustomerId = @CustomerId)
```

Using Linq-to-sql i'm trying to insert data from winforms to database.
In designer I have set insert behavior to my stored proc for both, class Customer and class Contact, but on

`_context.SubmitChanges();` got error

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CustomerContact". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.Customers", column 'CustomerId'.The statement has been terminated.`

Should i edit my stored procedure or handle that in code?

How to set `Contacts.CustomerId` when inserting child rows.

Comment: Why are you inserting a record with `CustomerName` then selecting a row with the `CustomerId`? You might look for the @@IDENTITY (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) or the SCOPE_IDENTITY() (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) methods. Assuming that the `Customers` table have an auto-inc primary key.

Comment: I have created that stored procedure from example Northwind stored procedure. Can u explain me what is problem with selecting CustomerId after insert? Also, should I have one stored procedure to use @@IDENTITY but what if on save I need to insert many child rows in different child tables like contacts, projects etc.

Comment: The procedure `InsertCustomers`. The first statement looks like the primary key is auto-inc, but you're passing the customerid as parameter. I think you should define the customerid as output parameter. `SET @CustomerId = @@IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stored procedures to insert data you can use simple Linq method to insert data.

```
DataClasseseMyDataContext db = new DataClasseseMyDataContext(conString);

db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(Customers);
tblSupplierPO.tblInvSupplierPOPIDetails.Add(Contacts);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

You must have created relationships among tables and add them to DBML

Comment: And how can I know if I need to to update or insert row. How to add multiple child rows. For example I need to insert one Customer with Three Contacts at the same time.

Comment: you can have different methods for Insert and Update
To insert multiple details you can have a List containing Contact Objects.By looping that list you can insert multiple details or you can insert all the details atonce.
'List<Contact> ContactList= YOUR CONTACT OBJECT  LIST ;
foreach(Contact c in ContactList)
{
tblSupplierPO.tblInvSupplierPOPIDetails.Add(c);
}'